# Data Tables: brake with url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, datatables

I have a situation with Data Tables that I don't understand:

**Problem:**

I have this rewriteRule:

```
Rewriterule ^table/ table.php
```

So, when I go to *www.site.com/table.php* all is working good but when I go to *www.site.com/table/* I have the next alert message:

> DataTables warning: table id={tablet} - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this problem go to: http://datatables.net/tn/1

I went to the suggest url but I can't fix the problem.

Sorry but I can not give the site online because is an intranet.

My php code is this:

```
$table = 'paciente';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 0),
    array( 
            'db' => 'nombre', 
            'dt' => 1,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links='<a href="paciente/'.$row[0].'/0/">'.$row[1].'</a>';
                return $links;
        }),
    array( 'db' => 'apellidos',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'tel_mov',   'dt' => 3,
     'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
         $tels=$row[3];
                return $tels;
         }
     ),
     array( 'db' => 'tel_casa',   'dt' => 4,
     'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
         $tels2=$row[4];
                return $tels2;
         }
     ),
    array( 'db' => 'terapeuta',     'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 6,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links2='<a href="print-historia.php?height=655&amp;width=800&amp;id='.$row[0].'" class=" thickbox"><img src="ima/edit.png" /></a> | <a href="?borrar=total&amp;id='.$row[0].'" onClick="return confirmSubmit()"><img src="ima/close.png" /></a>';
                return $links2;
        }),
);
require( 'libraries/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablet').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "js/Spanish.json"},
        "scrollY":        "500px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "pageLength": 25,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "table-load.php",
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "id","bVisible": false},
        { "sTitle": "Nombre" },
        { "sTitle": "Apellidos" },
        { "sTitle": "Móbil","bSortable": false },
        { "sTitle": "Fijo","bSortable": false },
        { "sTitle": "Terapeuta","bSortable": false },
        { "sTitle": "Edición","bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false }],
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        tb_init('a.thickbox');           
      }
        });
    } );
    </script>
```

Any idea?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you get a correct json response?

Comment: DataTables say not in the alert but when I go to  www.site.com/table.php there is no problem :(

Comment: `"ajax": "table-load.php",` ? what is your actual, real call that fails?

Comment: oh yea! is fixed! I needed the full url! `"ajax": "<?php echo $base; ?>table-load.php",`

Comment: @curosio If you've fixed your question You can add your own answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it in the javascript DataTable options with the full url in the ajax call:

```
"ajax": "<?php echo $base; ?>table-load.php"
```

**So the javascript is something like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $base; ?>js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablet').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "js/Spanish.json"},
    "scrollY":        "500px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "<?php echo $base; ?>table-load.php",
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "id","bVisible": false},
    { "sTitle": "Nombre" },
    { "sTitle": "Apellidos" },
    { "sTitle": "Móbil","bSortable": false },
    { "sTitle": "Fijo","bSortable": false },
    { "sTitle": "Terapeuta","bSortable": false },
    { "sTitle": "Edición","bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
    tb_init('a.thickbox');           
  }
    });
} );
</script>
```

**And the php:**

```
$table = 'paciente';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 0),
    array( 
            'db' => 'nombre', 
            'dt' => 1,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links='<a href="../paciente/'.$row[0].'/0/">'.$row[1].'</a>';
                return $links;
        }),
    array( 'db' => 'apellidos',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'tel_mov',   'dt' => 3,
     'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
         $tels=$row[3];
                return $tels;
         }
     ),
     array( 'db' => 'tel_casa',   'dt' => 4,
     'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
         $tels2=$row[4];
                return $tels2;
         }
     ),
    array( 'db' => 'terapeuta',     'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 6,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links2='<a href="../print-historia.php?height=655&amp;width=800&amp;id='.$row[0].'" class=" thickbox"><img src="ima/edit.png" /></a> | <a href="?borrar=total&amp;id='.$row[0].'" onClick="return confirmSubmit()"><img src="ima/close.png" /></a>';
                return $links2;
        }),
);
require( 'libraries/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

**Note that I put `../` behind the urls**

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem is that Datatable.js needs to read data from a "data" array key (extremely hard information to find in their docs honestly).

This mean that you need to adjust your PHP script to get an array which has this structure:

```
"success" => true|false // useful to display errors
"message" => string // explains the error (if occurred)
"data" => array // contains all your data
```

**EDIT**

This is an example of a PHP array which is ready to be encoded and handled by DataTable.js. Note the array key "data": DataTable.js will search for elements to display in that jsonResponse.data.

```
<?php

// data fetched from database
$fromDatabase = [
    'example',
    'test',
    'foo',
    'bar'
];

$response = [

    'success' => true,
    'message' => '',
    'data' => $fromDatabase
];

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: uops, sorry but I'm not a really php programmer :( can you explain me with more details? thanks!!!

Comment: thanks but I fixed just davidkonrad suggest in the comments.